# How can I use data & computed properties instead of Event Bus to communicate between components?

Tags: vue.js

I have a button and an `Overlay` component in `myComponent`. `openOverlay` is triggered on button click. `openOverlay` emits `openedOverlay` via EventBus.

```
 <button
      @click="openOverlay"
</button>
<Overlay />

  methods: {
    openOverlay() {
      EventBus.$emit("openedOverlay");
    },
  },
```

`Overlay` component listens to `openedOverlay` via EventBus. `openedOverlay` changes `overlayOpen` to true and displays Modal component.

```
    <Modal
      v-if="overlayOpen"
      :overlayOpen="overlayOpen"
    />

  data() {
    return {
      overlayOpen: false,
    };
  },

 mounted() {
    EventBus.$on("openedOverlay", () => {
      this.openMyOverlay();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    openMyOverlay() {
      this.overlayOpen = true;
    },
  },
```

How can I use data & computed properties instead of Event Bus to communicate between components?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to communicate between components.
You can use vuex and put into global store flag for overlay opening. Then you will be able to control it from anywhere in you vue components hierarchy.
Also you can use RxJs (ohhh,I love this library, but you should use it in a smart way to prevent memory leakage). There you can create a Subject, subscribe on it in your overlay, and pass it as a prop to children. Then these children can generate next value.
If you insist that you need to use data & computed
These decisions are more flexible then the approach you are going to perform:
To perform it you should simply pass as a prop to the Overlay component some flag, which represents necessity of modal being opened.

```
     <button
      @click="openOverlay = true"
</button>
<Overlay v-model="openOverlay"/>

  data() {
    return {openOverlay: false}
  },
```

and the next snippet:

```
<Modal
  v-if="value"
  :overlayOpen="value"
/>
<button @click="$emit('change', false)">close overlay</button>


   data() {
     props: [
       value // here your v-model :)
     ];
   },
```

Comment: sorry for bad formatting. Typing it from phone. Also I'd advise to take a look at https://github.com/javisperez/vuedals. It's really awesome library for modals